# how to get used ram while running a jar

Tags: java, batch-file, ram

Hello so i am trying to create a script ( .bat file) to run the same jar many times simultanly (20 to 50 times )  and  i want to get the execution time of every jar  i did this using

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
System.out.println(elapsedTime/1000+"s");
```

but what i want now is to get how much ram i am using while executing this (20 to 50) jars ?
my .bat file is something like this :

```
@echo off
start java -jar checkUrl.jar 

start java -jar checkUrl.jar 

start java -jar checkUrl.jar 

pause
```

if you are asking me while i am doing this , i can explain because this jar will be runned many times on the same laptop ( there is a supervision software which will use this jar ) so i need it to be fast this is why i am trying to get those information

Thanks

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a java profiling tool that will monitor the operations at the JVM level. It will provide you with CPU & Memory usages as well as lots of useful metrics for optimizing your code.
You can look into these tools: JProfiler, YourKit, or Java VisualVM.

However this is one way to measure memory consumption programatically.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println(runtime.freeMemory());
```